# docker-compose detaches from containers after going up

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I'm experiencing a very weird issue inside the terminal.

I am using docker-compose to start my microservices, and when I run `docker-compose up`  I see  all the logs that containers are producing immediately.

However, just after `docker-compose up` completes, there are no more new logs generated by containers, like if the terminal has detached from the containers. If I then run in a new terminal `docker-compose restart my-service` I will then again see the logs in the old terminal, but it is very annoying to do that each time.

I'm using Linux Mint 19.2 and this happens in both default terminal app and also in Guake terminal. On Windows, using git-bash, I never had this  issue. Is there something I can do to solve this issue, and does anyone know why it's happening ?